# Trouble with generics using custom equality comparison

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a class heirarchy as follows:

```
public abstract class Issue
{
    // some base properties
    // these are not included in equality checks for deriving classes
    // also not performing equality checks on this base class (it is abstract anyway)
}

public class IssueTypeA : Issue, IEquatable<IssueTypeA>
{
    // some properties specific to this class
    // these are the two for which equality comparison is performed
    public string requirement { get; set; }
    public string preamble { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(IssueTypeA that)
    {
        // determine based on the values of the properties
        // they must both be the same for equality
        if ((this.requirement.Equals(that.requirement)) &&
           (this.preamble.Equals(that.preamble)))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

public class IssueTypeB : Issue, IEquatable<IssueTypeB>
{
    // some properties specific to this class

    public bool Equals(IssueTypeB that)
    {
        // determine based on the values of the properties
    }
}
```

There is another class, intended to receive objects in the above heirarchy (except the base class, of course), and do some comparison operations with them:

```
public class Comparer<T> where T : Issue
{
    // various comparison methods
    public IEnumerable<T> getReferenceChangedIssues(IEnumerable<T> spreadsheetIssues, IEnumerable<T> downloadedIssues)
    {
        foreach (T spreadsheetRecord in T spreadsheetIssues)
        {
            foreach (T downloadedIssue in downloadedIssues)
            {
                // this is the point of failure
                // there are cases in which this should be true, but it is not
                if (spreadsheetRecord.Equals(downloadedIssue))
                {
                    // the referenceChanged method works fine by itself
                    // it has been unit tested
                    if (spreadsheetRecord.referenceChanged(downloadedIssue))
                        yield return spreadsheetRecord;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Through unit testing and debugging, it's apparent that the **custom** `Equals` methods defined above are not being used correctly by `Comparer`. Why is this? It is also intended to include methods with some set operations in the future, which will need `Equals`.

Comment: What if to Compare you're given one `IssueTypeA` and one `IssueTypeB`, which `Equals` method would it call?

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich I have not tried that. I will do, but in normal circumstances two different subtypes of `Issue` would not be mixed. Perhaps generics are not suitable here.

Comment: If you implement *IEquatable* you should also override *Object.Equals* and *Object.GetHashCode*. What methods *Comparer* include? Does it implement interface *IComparer*? What problems do you face in the methods of *Comparer*?

Comment: @IliarTurdushev I will add an example of a method included in `Comparer`.

Comment: @Al2110 Now I see that the problem in the definition of the class `Comparer`. When you call `spreadsheetRecord.Equals(downloadedIssue)` a method `Object.Equals` is invoked (instead of `IEquatable.Equals`), because type `T` of `Comparer` does not constrained to implement `IEquatable`. Change the definition of the `Comparer` to the next: `class Comparer<T> where T : Issue, IEquatable<T>`. And also consider overriding `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode` in your `Issue` classes.

Answer (score 0):

When you implement IEquatable, you really need to override `bool Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode`.  If you don't do that, things will break in weird ways.  This was the stripped-down-est thing I could come up with.  I think it should solve your issue (but I can't really tell without your comparison code).  If folks point out issues, I'll fix up the code:

```
public abstract class Issue : IEquatable<Issue>
{
    // possibly (not not necessarily) some base properties
    // if they are included, make them part of the equality comparison and
    // include them in the HashCode calculations

    public bool Equals(Issue other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.GetType() != other.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }
        //test local properties and return true/false based on their values
        return true;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Issue) obj);
    }

}

public class IssueTypeA : Issue, IEquatable<IssueTypeA>
{
    public string AName { get; set; } = "My A Name";
    public int AValue { get; set; } = 42;

    public bool Equals(IssueTypeA other)
    {
        if (!base.Equals(other))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return AName == other.AName && AValue == other.AValue;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((IssueTypeA) obj);
    }


    //hash-codes need to be consistent once they are calculated - jump through some hoops
    private int? _hashCodeValue = default;
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (!_hashCodeValue.HasValue)
        {
            _hashCodeValue = $"{AName}{AValue}".GetHashCode();
        }

        return _hashCodeValue.Value;
    }
}

public class IssueTypeB : Issue, IEquatable<IssueTypeB>
{
    // some properties specific to this class
    public string BName { get; set; } = "My B Name";
    public int BValue { get; set; } = 84;



    public bool Equals(IssueTypeB other)
    {
        if (!base.Equals(other))
        {
            return false;
        }
        //calculate equality based on local properties and return true/false
        return BName == other.BName && BValue == other.BValue;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((IssueTypeB) obj);
    }

    //hash-codes need to be consistent once they are calculated - jump through some hoops
    private int? _hashCodeValue = default;
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (!_hashCodeValue.HasValue)
        {
            _hashCodeValue = $"{BName}{BValue}".GetHashCode();
        }

        return _hashCodeValue.Value;
    }
}
```

This is a better stab at a solution than the first pass.  I check for equality based on properties local to each class.  I also provide a `GetHashCode` implementation that is consistent (in the weird way that I believe `GetHashCode` requires - but in a way that drive Resharper nuts).

Comment: I added to the original post, the properties for which the equality comparison for `IssueTypeA` is based. I see you gave an example in your answer for the case that base properties are used in the comparison. In my case, they are not. Do I still need the equals and get hash code methods in the base class?